# Sampling without replacement - Sec 3.5, Chap.3, Blitzstein and Hwang, Intro to Probability

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, symmetry, sampling

I have an elementary question on sampling without replacement, but I thought I must ask here, to be sure I've understood it.

> Example. There are 100 slips of paper in a hat, each of which has one
>   of the numbers $1,2,3,\ldots,100$ written on it, with no number
>   appearing more than once. Five of the slips are drawn one at a time.
>
> Consider sampling without replacement (with all sets of five slips
>   equally likely to be chosen).
>
> What is the distribution(PMF) of the value of the $j$th draw?

Solution.

The author in the book writes,

> Let $Y_{j}$ be the value of the $j$th draw. By symmetry, $Y_{j}$
>   follows $\text{DUnif}(1,2,\ldots,100)$. Here learning any $Y_{i}$
>   gives information about the other values (so $Y_{1},\ldots,Y_{5}$ are
>   not independent), but symmetry still holds since, unconditionally, the
>   $j$th slip drawn is equally likely to be any of the slips.

The author writes that the $j$th draw is essentially equivalent to sampling one object from the set $\{1,2,\ldots,100\}$. If sampling were with replacement, this is certainly true. But, when sampling without replacement, wouldn't I be left with only $100-(j-1)$ numbers to choose from, on the $j$th draw? I know there's a fallacy in my thinking there. But, I can't tell what.

Any inputs and intuition would be great help!

Cheers and thanks,

Quasar C.

Comment: the symmetry still holds, with or without replacement.  Think of just two slips, numbered $\{1,2\}$.  What's the distribution of the second card drawn?  Well, you either draw, in order, $(1,2)$ or $(2,1)$ so it is $\frac 12$ either way.  Now try three slips...stopping when you are persuaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sampling without replacement would make a difference **if you knew what you've already sampled**, but you don't know what you've drawn before the jth draw.

It's like computing the probability of drawing ace of spades from a nonstandard deck with one unknown card already removed. It's not 1/51. It's 1/51 **assuming the card removed is not the ace of spades**.

So it's $(1/51)(51/52) + (0/52)(1/52) =1/52$.

In your case the probability that $Y_j$ is for example 10 is not $1/(100-(j-1))$ but rather

$1/(100-(j-1)) (100-(j-1))/(100) + 0/(100-(j-1)) (j-1)/(100) = 1/100$

Hence the $Y_j$'s are identically distributed but not independent.

So for example

$P(Y_2 = 67) = 1/100$

But

$P(Y_2 = 67 | Y_1 = 41) = 1/99$

Comment: helped clear major confusion, thanks! I took this down as an aside in my notes. I jumped directly to the topic - 'Random variables' without reading counting methods and conditioning & independence. Hence, the doubt. :)